# Why should I need 125 reputation to vote down an answer to my own question?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

I understand the reason behind requiring a certain amount of reputation for up/down voting privileges, but why should I need 125 to down vote the answers given to my own question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To put it bluntly, new users are less trustworthy. I have in fact seen many antagonistic users attacking people who answer their questions (even when the answer is solid, provably correct, and polite) because they don't like the solution offered. More often than not, the antagonistic questioners are new users.

Comment: I do agree with you, but shouldn't be a way be provided to cover such situations. 2 months ago I asked a question, some one gave me a down vote without answering anything or giving a comment, after lots of searches (and getting no answer from anyone) I posted the problem to Microsoft Connect, and they replied me after 2 days that it's a VS.NET BUG.

Comment: but I already lost some reputations!

Comment: Yeah, people do sometimes incorrectly vote down questions - hopefully it doesn't happen that often.

Comment: @Afshin And what exactly does this have to do with **answers**? You seem to be talking about downvotes on questions.

Comment: +1. Avoiding rage downvote is worth it.

Comment: @slhck you are right, actually it's 2 different thing. but the idea behind both is to have some kind of feature to (1)'downvote' wrong/unrelated answers and (2) have some kind of 'un-fair' downvotes deletion feature. I don't know, maybe I'm very idealist?!

Comment: @Afshin Well, who gets to decide what is unfair? I think you're taking it too seriously. There are a few downvotes here and there, but it doesn't hurt.. I've got a few too, I wouldn't worry so much.